# How to handle calculations done inside a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a join statement that looks like so:

```
... FROM
        table1 act
    JOIN
        table2 ti
    ON
        act.CD_AGENT = ti.CD_AGENT --
        AND 
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START >= DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, 0, (act.[DT_START_TIME])) / @increment) * @increment, 0)
        AND
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START < DATEADD(minute, IIF(ISNULL(act.[DT_END_TIME], @enddate_nullreplacement) > DATEADD(minute, CEILING(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, ISNULL(act.[DT_END_TIME], @enddate_nullreplacement)) / CAST(@increment AS float)) * @increment, 0), @increment, 0), DATEADD(minute, CEILING(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, ISNULL(act.[DT_END_TIME], @enddate_nullreplacement)) / CAST(@increment AS float)) * @increment, 0))
    WHERE ...
```

I suspect that those calculations inside the join have a negative impact on my performance.
Do you see an elegant way to improve it? I considered having the calculations before in a temporary table or maybe add the results in an additional column. What do you think?

Comment: *"I suspect that those calculations inside the join have a negative impact on my performance"* They will as they make the query non-SARGable. Some sample data and expected results may well help us help you here. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: make table2 to a subquery and calculate the data there, then you compare it

Comment: The predicate in the `ON` clause generates a dependency of `act` from `t2`. That means that `act` could still work decently well as a driving table, if there's an index on `table2 (CD_AGENT, DT_INTERVAL_START)`. The `WHERE` predicates also affect the performance so please add them to the question as well.

Comment: For performance questions, we need to see at a minimum: your *full* query, your tables *and index* defintions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. This question is not really answerable otherwise. SQL Performance questions don't usually have a straight "do this don't do that" answer.

Comment: As mentioned by @TheImpaler it depends which table is better indexed and can be subject to a nested loop/index seek pair. If `table2` can do so then your existing query is not that bad. Otherwise you might need to flip round the calculation so that it is on `table2` rather than `table1`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for simplifying your query. I don't think they will significantly change performance, but can make the code more readable. A few opinions on the expected execution plan follow.

If you find yourself dealing with complicated expressions that hinder readability, it is sometimes advantageous to break out the calculations into a `CROSS APPLY`. One of  the uses for a cross apply is to encapsulate intermediate calculations whose results can be utilized later in the join sequence.

Something like:

```
... FROM
        table1 act
    CROSS APPLY (
        select
            longExpression AS FromDate,
            anotherLongExpression AS ToDate
    ) calc
    JOIN
        table2 ti
    ON
        act.CD_AGENT = ti.CD_AGENT
        AND 
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START >= calc.FromDate
        AND
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START < Calc.ToDate
    WHERE ....
```

Multiple `CROSS APPLY`s can be used in sequence if you wish you build up your calculations, particularly if you have repeated sub-expressions.

```
... FROM
        table1 act
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            ISNULL(act.[DT_END_TIME], @enddate_nullreplacement)
                AS EndDate1
    ) c1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(minute, CEILING(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, c1.EndDate1) / CAST(@increment AS float)) * @increment, 0)
                AS EndDate2
    ) c2
    CROSS APPLY (
        select
            DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, 0, (act.[DT_START_TIME])) / @increment) * @increment, 0)
                AS FromDate,
            DATEADD(minute, IIF(c1.EndDate1 > c2.EndDate2, @increment, 0), c2.EndDate2)
                AS ToDate
    ) c3
    JOIN
        table2 ti
    ON
        act.CD_AGENT = ti.CD_AGENT
        AND 
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START >= c3.FromDate
        AND
        ti.DT_INTERVAL_START < c3.ToDate
    WHERE ....
```

I believe the above is equivalent to your original query, but you should double check the work.

There might also be a case for breaking some of your date-rounding calculations out into a couple of user-defined functions. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DateTimeRoundMinutes(@dt DATETIME, @increment INT, @roundUp BIT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS ...
```

As for query execution efficiency, I believe the most likely execution plan would:

1. Select rows from table1 (preferably via an index that efficiently filters for conditions in the WHERE clause)
2. Calculate a few values
3. Use those values to perform a loop join into the Table2 (preferably via an index on `Table2(CD_AGENT, DT_INTERVAL_START)`).

Both of the above table accesses would likely be executed as an index seek followed by a primary key lookup. Assuming that the necessary indexes are in place, I think the performance should be pretty good.

Even without restructuring your original query, I expect the execution plan would be similar. I suggest that you try both the original and restructured queries and review the execution plans. If comparable, go with what you judge to be more readable and maintainable.

(The above assumes an execution plan that accesses Table1 first and Table2 second. Given the join condition calculations, I believe there is little chance that the SQL Server could generating an efficient execution plan that accessed Table2 first.)